# CSS Vertical Alignment of SPAN

Tags: css

I can't seem to vertically align the spans in my real basic code.

Here is the CSS:

```
.BigGreyTitle {font-size: 22px;
    color: #676767;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.f1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial,'Lucida Grande','Bitstream Vera Sans',verdana,sans-serif;
}

.mainlink-u a {
    color: #EF3834;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here is the HTML Markup:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="BigGreyTitle" align="left">All Members In Montana</td>
    <td align="right">
    <span><img src="http://www.coalprepdir.com/images/schemes/red/ret_arrow.png" style="border:none" alt=""/></span>
    <span style="padding-left:5px" class="f1 mainlink-u"><a href="distribution_us_stats.asp">Go Back To US Distribution</a></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/sJA92/

Any help to get these vertically aligned would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks!

Comment: Vertically aligned how?

Comment: You'll probably have to tweak it with margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a rule to vertically align the image to the middle.

```
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sJA92/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
span {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJA92/1/

For another level of vertical alignment (baseline, middle, bottom...) you'll need to adjust them with padding and margins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to float the spans.
I set the td to align middle also.
See this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/sJA92/6/

```
td{
    vertical-align:middle
}
td span{
   float: left
}
```